# Duplicate app logo when downloading Android App

Tags: android, duplication

Whenever I run an Android app from eclipse and downloaded into a phone,there will be a duplication of the application I downloaded. For instance my app is called "MyAndroidApp" and when I run it into my phone, there is two application of "MyAndroidApp". Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your manifest, you must have two

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

declared